# jQuery code doesn't work on Google Chrome?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-animate

This code doesn't work on google chroome but works on Firefox, opera, and IE

```
function show() {
    $('#networks').click(function () {
        $('#social').slideDown(1000);
        $('#face,#twitter,#google,#youtube,#rss').fadeIn(2000)
    });

    $('#networks').blur(function () {
        $('#face,#twitter,#google,#youtube,#rss').fadeOut(1000);
        $('#social').delay(1000).slideUp(1000);
    });
}
```

at the same documents after this code i wrote the code below and work on google chroome and all other browsers, why this code works well in google chroome but above doesn't ???

```
function UseData() {

    $("#submit").click(function () {

        $(this).val("");
        $(this).animate({
            width: '250px',
        }, "slow")

    });

    $("#submit").blur(function () {
        $(this).val("Search");
        $(this).animate({
            width: '175px',
        }, "slow");
    });
}
```

thanks

Comment: How should it work or rather, what doesn't work?

Comment: What's not working? What's the intended result? Do you have a site or a jsfiddle you can point us to? There could be problems in your HTML? We really have no idea.

Comment: when i click on networks div, should social div show up, this work in all browsers but chroome doesn't ??

Comment: so why works on all browsers but chroome doesn't ??

Comment: Can you give us a link to the current state of your work? (Best as a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net))

Comment: i'm working localhost !

Comment: Without more informations about your problem, we cannot help you! Upload the part which doesn't work on a server, or better: Prepare a **[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net)**.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/A4CJz/

Comment: @MohammedF.Ghazo before posting a fiddle, at least make sure it works.  Here's updated fiddle settings so it at least runs (images don't load, but you get the gist): http://jsfiddle.net/A4CJz/1/

Comment: Why are you using `onfocus` instead of `onclick` for the anchor?

Comment: updated link http://jsfiddle.net/A4CJz/9/ i just want social div show up when click on networks

Comment: @MohammedF.Ghazo It makes no sense to attach a the event-handlers in an event-handler... Why you don't attach your event-handlers directly? And by the way, as I [noted](http://stackoverflow.com/a/17124494/1250044) already, the `focus`-event doesn't work on `a`-nodes, use `onclick` instead.

Comment: @yckart it works on http://jsfiddle.net/A4CJz/11/ but on google chroome doesn't ??

Comment: @MohammedF.Ghazo see my answer too... it's probably a combination of both our answers.  Your markup needs to be fixed for it to work in chrome.

Comment: @MohammedF.Ghazo And of course, both of our *options* work in chrome.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

http://jsfiddle.net/A4CJz/10/

I believe the effect you want is this:

- when the mouse hovers over the element (not `focus`) then show the social menu
- when the mouse leaves the element (not `blur`) then hide the social menu

Your markup was atrocious.  That's why it wasn't working in chrome.  You really need to learn valid markup and valid JS before this solution will be helpful.  In particular, you cannot wrap an `a` tag around an `li` tag in a list.  The only valid child of  `ul` is `li`.

You also don't need to id each of the `li` elements and target them directly.  A quick lesson in jquery will show you that you can target by the tag name, which you will see me do in the example fiddle I posted, as such: `$('#social li')`

I also did away with your inline JS and used jquery to wire up the `mouseenter` and `mouseleave` events.

I recommend you study the code carefully and try to understand how and why I restructured your code the way I did.

Comment: I believe he wants a `click` state-toggle, instead of `hover` ;)

Answer (score 1):

Okay, at the first your fiddle depends on `jQuery` so you've to include it. The second thing is that you've to load your script in the `head` to work with `inline`-code. (`onclick`-handlers on `html`-tags). Otherwise your `function` 'll be undefined ;-)

But to point out what your real problem is, there's nothing special needed. An `a`-tag cannot handle `focus` or `blur`-events.

You can read more here: http://api.jquery.com/focus/#entry-longdesc

The working fiddle:

http://fiddle.jshell.net/A4CJz/3/

Another tip, prevent the default action of your attached `event`, to kill its normal behaviour. Simply done with `preventDefault` on the `event`-object or an simple `return false` at the end of your event-handler function.

**Update**

http://fiddle.jshell.net/A4CJz/12/

Comment: I agree this works, but I don't think it's a great solution to his problem.  The method named `show` has nothing to do with *show*ing anything.  And his markup still might cause some massive issues down the road.  I'm not fighting for him to accept my answer or anything -- I can make due without the 15 points :)  But I think if he uses this solution, while it might work for this hurdle, he'll be back when the rest of it starts to blow up!  Cheers

Comment: Edit: I see you added a fiddle v12.  That looks better.  Click-toggle might be what he wants, I agree.  The combination of our two answers -- my markup fixes and simplification of JS, your click handling -- is probably the best answer.  Feel free to mod my fiddle and edit your answer if you want.  I'll leave my answer as is for reference case mouse enter / leave.

Comment: Yeah, and that's the way stackoverflow, nor?! We don't want to keep the peoples in shit, we want to help them out!

Comment: @yckart ur http://fiddle.jshell.net/A4CJz/12/ doesn't work on all browsers, i'm fresh in jquery, so tell me the right solution please ?

Comment: @MohammedF.Ghazo That depends not on my solution rather then your `html` & `css`.